# Closing powershell window closes my program as well

Tags: powershell

This is my first attempt at automating some of my development environment setup. I have the following powershell script:

```
& "C:\MAMP\MAMP.exe"
& "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"
```

I run it and it works fine, but when I close the powershell window it closes my VS Code window as well. MAMP stays open.

I'm sure this is a simple fix. Thanks!

Comment: Weird. I just tried running VS Code in that way and when I closed the PowerShell window, it stayed open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with Start-Process?

Start-Process "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"